# Generating Regex Patterns from a List of Srings in C++

Tags: c++, regex

Let's say I have a list of prefix strings:

```
Windows 7
Windows 8
MSIE 10
Windows NT
Apple .0
etc...
```

These are all possible prefixes for my target string. For example, `Windows 7.1` would match with `Windows 7`. `Apple` **would NOT** match with `Apple .0` .

Since my list of prefixes can get quite long, I would rather a fast approach to **check if my target string contains any of the prefixes without iterating through the entire list.**

Is there any way to automatically take a list of strings like this and **generate a single regex that will accomplish the task of checking if any of the prefixes are in my target string.**

I know it is possible to do this naively using regex, but this wouldn't be any better than just iterating through my list. Ideally the regex would be optimized (similar to how a trie is optimized).

Comment: What programming langaue it is?

Comment: You can check it using binary search. You won't iterate through entire list and also don't need to generate regex.

Comment: You can't check every string in the list without iterating through it (in some fashion). If you want fast then I would not use regex, just do direct string comparison.

Comment: @Galik Correct but misleading: you can write code that only iterates through the list of prefixes *once*, even when checking many input strings against those prefixes. OP’s regex idea does in fact work like that, and is quite a bit more efficient than iterating over all prefixes for every test string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do this. Just join the prefixes by `|` and surround the whole thing with `^(…)` (to anchor it at the beginning of the string).

Then you can generate a `std::regex` object based on that string, and match it against your input(s). Here’s an example that constructs the regex pattern at runtime:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename C>
std::string join(C const& strings, std::string const& delim) {
    std::ostringstream ostr;
    auto last = std::prev(std::end(strings));
    std::copy(
        std::begin(strings), last,
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(ostr, delim.c_str())
    );
    ostr << *last;
    return ostr.str();
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::string_literals;

    auto const prefix_str = "^("s + join(std::vector<char const*>{
        "Windows 7",
        "Windows 8",
        "MSIE 10",
        "Windows NT",
        "Apple \\.0"
    }, "|") + ")";
    std::regex const prefix_pattern{prefix_str};

    std::vector<std::string> const inputs{"Windows 8.1", "Apple", "Apple .01"};

    for (auto const& input : inputs) {
        std::smatch match;
        if (regex_search(input, match, prefix_pattern)) {
            std::cout << "Matched \"" << input << "\" against \"" << match.str() << "\"\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed to match \"" << input << "\"\n";
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Live code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d90adcc74c5e89a)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This will work, although I am concerned that this regex will effectively still be iterating through the entire list by virtue of all the "|" . I probably need to look into a trie or something if I want a more efficient approach.

Comment: @Blondie No, that’s not how regular expression matching works. Instead, it uses a state machine that checks a given input position against all possible corresponding states of the regex. A more sophisticated version of this is the [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm), which would probably be the optimal solution to your problem. But a well-implemented regex engine should come very close (that said, as far as I’m aware no C++ standard library implementation has a g “good” regex engine).

Comment: Wow, very informative. I was unaware how regex works internally. Thanks a lot.